# salesforce url hacking for standard fields

Tags: urlhacking

I have created a report on the opportunity report and this is my report url: https://na19.salesforce.com//00O130000090Ae6?pc0=&Name&pn0=&eq&&pv0=&Ship_To_Company_Name__c

and the filters are as follows:
    Account Name contains  Clear 
    AND Opportunity Record Type equals Standard Opportunity Clear 
    AND Stage equals Suspect,Prospect,Target,Commit Clear

The primary object for the report is Opportunity. I want to do a url hack to make Account Name = Ship_To_Company_Name__c.

Is there anyway I can do it. The hack works for custom objects but I cannot figure it out for Standard Object.

Comment: I don't think you can filter one field equal to another like that.

Comment: You have two // in the url, merge fields are not correct. That URL will not work even for standard objects

Comment: I tried with custom fields and it worked. I don't know how to do it with Standard fields. The reason is Standard fields do not have a id like in custom fields on the object.

Comment: I'm with Adrian here ... filter of fieldX = fieldY isn't supported as `pv0` is a scalar, special date filter,  or list of scalars/special date filters compared against the value of fieldX `(pc0)`  If you need to do what you asked, put a Boolean formula field in the Opportunity object `IsAccountNameSameAsShipToName__c`